# Get Python tuple in different format

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a python tuple like so,

```
((1420455415000L, 2L), (1420545729000L, 3L), (1420653453000L, 2L))
```

I want to convert it into this format:

```
[[1420455415000, 2], [1420545729000, 3], [1420653453000, 2]]
```

Please note that I also want to remove the 'L' that is automatically removed when I convert this tuple to dict. I have converted the tuple of tuples to list using :

```
def listit(t):
        return list(map(listit, t)) if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)) else t
```

but the L still remains. That is a problem because I am sending the data to Javascript

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're passing the data to JavaScript, you can do this trivially with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation) module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(((1420455415000L, 2L), (1420545729000L, 3L), (1420653453000L, 2L)))
'[[1420455415000, 2], [1420545729000, 3], [1420653453000, 2]]'
```

Comment: This is what I originally tried by after convert it to dict(k ) which didn't give the desired outpu. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

To get the output in your question you could use

```
t = ((1420455415000L, 2L), (1420545729000L, 3L), (1420653453000L, 2L))

l = [map(int,x) for x in t]
```

The conversion from `long` to `int` would only work if the value was less than or equal to `sys.maxint`. Otherwise it will stay as a long. The conversion is not necessary though as the `L` is only really denoting the type and not the value.

If you are passing it to javascript, the conversion to json makes more sense.

Comment: You do realize that long integers are nevertheless integers, and casting won't do anything if the numbers are too large.

Answer (score 0):

`L` denotes that the numbers is of type `long` , if you are 100% sure that the number would be less than the limit that `int` can handle (in python , which means on conversion to int it would remain int and not revert back to long , which can happen if the number is very very large), then you can simply convert by using `int(num)` . But please note, `L` is just an internal representation and it would not show up when the number is converted to string (or printed, for which it is internally converted to string) , it will only show up when using `repr()` .

Example -

```
>>> i = 2L
>>> i
2L
>>> int(i)
2
>>> print i
2
>>> str(i)
'2'
>>> i
2L
```

In your case, to convert longs to int inside a list use -

```
>>> l = [1L , 2L , 3L]
>>> print l
[1L, 2L, 3L]
>>> l = map(int, l)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3]
```

If its possible that the lists have sublists, use a recursive function such as -

```
def convertlist(l):
    if isinstance(l , (list, tuple)):
        return list(map(convertlist, l))
    elif isinstance(l , long):
        return int(l)
    else:
        return l
>>> l = [1L , 2L , [3L]]
>>> convertlist(l)
[1, 2, [3]]
```

Comment: Yes , I mean a number which will change to int when passed .

Comment: Edited and changed the wording .

Answer (score 0):

'L' merely indicates variable's type, in this case Long Integer. Hence whatever the way you are sending the data it will behave as an Int.

That said, if you really don't want to see that 'L' you would need to change the type into integer with simple [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):